# Pushwoosh device ready fails to function when redircting URL in index.html page (android, ios, windows phone)

Tags: windows-phone-8, phonegap-build, pushwoosh

i am have created a app for Android, iPhone and Windows phone using Phonegap build and in my index.html page i am using this code

```
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
         <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
         <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushwooshAndroid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushwooshiOS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "http://google.com/"
    </script>

</body>
```

But when the site is redirected by using **window.location.href** pushwoosh deviceready fails to function and app is not getting registered pushwoosh.

is there any way i can redirected and pushwoosh deviceready can function.

at this point in time help much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand what are you doing. By changing window.location.href you are stopping all Javascript execution on the page, **redirecting** and loading another page. Javascript from the original page (index.html) is no longer working because the webview is loading another webpage!

Try to use iframe in index.html (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) or ChildBrowser plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser/, https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/480)